# nginx display a html and redirect after 10 seconds

Tags: nginx

I have an application running on a webserver behind nginx. During maintenance time, I need to display some message to users. I want to put this message in html in nginx and display it for few seconds and redirect back to application url. Is this possible in nginx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following redirect is a client-side logic.
Nginx can do nothing in this case

Comment: Thanks for this comment. It makes sense, once a page is loaded it is on client, and nginx can't make client redirect to another page. I am accepting this as correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Its possible with javascript, create an html page, then in script tag in head section, add given javascript

```
setTimeout(function()     
  {  window.location="http://YOURWEBSITEURL";
  }, 10000);
```

Comment: Thanks for response. But I am looking for nginx based solution.

Comment: ngix is not a programming language in which you can create a page or code the logic to wait then redirect

Comment: https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#name